# How do I fix the boost/asio c++ exception error?

Tags: c++

I am trying to connect to the localhost port and I am getting the following error, how can I fix this error ?

" terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl >'
  what():  connect: Connection refused "

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
boost::system::error_code ec;
using namespace boost::asio;

io_service svc;
ip::tcp::socket sock(svc);
sock.connect({ {}, 3000 }); // localhost port

std::string response;

do {
    char buf[2048];
    size_t bytes_transferred = sock.receive(buffer(buf), {}, ec);
    if (!ec) response.append(buf, buf + bytes_transferred);
} while (!ec);

// print and exit
std::cout << response <<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Well, what's listening on port 3000?  Are you sure anything is?

Comment: port 3000 is free .. nothing is listening to it .. I chose it because I have no services on it ..

Comment: What are you connecting to, if nothing is listening? Makes no sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't connect to a port with nothing listening to it.  That's what Connection Refused means: "nothing is here to respond to your request."

You will have to run or use some other server for a connect() to succeed.

If you're using a unix like system, you can probably use a tool like [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) to quickly throw together a service to listen on a port that you can then connect to.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have a reverse tunnel on this port and I want to get some info by listening to it. is this the suitable way to do it ?

Comment: If you want to listen on port 3000, you need to use sock.listen() and sock.accept(), not sock.connect.  I do not know enough about boosts implementation to give you code for that.